# Compare SharePoint list forms and Access web apps in SharePoint Office 365

Tags: sharepoint, web-applications, office365, ms-access-2013

Someone please provide pros and cons,a comparison between SharePoint list and Access web apps since both for the purpose of data collection?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little all over the place since there was 2 different versions of Access Web Applications.  With that said, it is pretty much a moot point now that Access Web Apps have been deprecated:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-Services-in-SharePoint-Roadmap-497fd86b-e982-43c4-8318-81e6d3e711e8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

While support will last a lot longer in the on premises version of SharePoint I don't think anyone would advise you to start new work using that technology.